# AOSP make verbose

Tags: build, android-source, verbose

How to see verbose compile command in AOSP build? ndk-build provides V=1 option. What about build from source? May I type similar to

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch 
make liblog V=1
```

and see raw compiler execution lines?

Comment: Since the change to `soong` build system the full commands can be found using: `gzip -cd out/verbose.log.gz | less -R`

Answer (score 22):

If you want to see the full compile/link/whatever commands being run, use the special *showcommands* target (which isn't a target to build per se, but a modifier to the output of the make command). E.g.: to build liblog you would do:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch    
$ make showcommands liblog
```

Comment: This is what works for me on AOSP version 9

Answer (score 12):

For someone seeking the answer on the Android build versions `10+`

```
! The argument `showcommands` is no longer supported.
! Instead, the verbose log is always written to a compressed file in the output dir:
!
!   gzip -cd out/verbose.log.gz | less -R
!
! Older versions are saved in verbose.log.#.gz files
```

Here `out` is the directory located at `<build_root>/out` . This is taken from the code in the soong files [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/cmd/soong_ui/main.go#482). This change was introduced with [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/b82471ad6dfec4790b2d86e49525dadc3fc06416%5E%21/) commit.

Comment: Can you tell as which versions qualify as "later" ? This log file does not seem to exist on AOSP 9

Comment: @Ber I've added the clarification and added the commit that changed the logging.